# I am unable to find the styles file in the Values folder in Android development

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am new to Android Development and cannot find the styles file in the Values folder. Am I misunderstanding something? Is there another way to style buttons since I cannot override pre-defined styles? Please help me find any alternative solutions to this problem and any suggestions for how to proceed as a beginner?

Answer (score 0):

well by defualt there is no styles.xml file .... you have the themes.xml file only and you should create the styles file by your self ...right click and new android resource file and create it

Comment: Thanks for your help but if there is not styles folder, How can I add custom styles and over ride the previous styles...Are we supposed to define the styles ourselves?